# Auto populate address details when user type from aws location service for single line text question using SurveyJS Survey Creater

Tags: angular, surveyjs

Is it possible to facilitate the below using the SurveyJS Survey Creator module?

1. Is it possible to introduce AWS location service to a single-line text question for address lookups
2. For the populated single-line text, is it possible to set values to other fields?
3. After population, can those fields still be editable by the user
   eg :
   Field 1 - Address-(single line text question that needs to be populated by AWS location service)
   Field 2 - City:(Other field that needs to be filled based on field 1)
   Field 3 - Post Code:(Other field that needs to be filled based on field 1)
   Field 4 - Suburb:(Other field that needs to be filled based on field 1)

After population, the user should be able to edit all of the fields above

Answer (score 0):

Sounds doable but bear in mind that the default rate limit on the AWS Locations API is 50 requests per second. You can apply to have the limit raised. You probably dont want to make a new query each time the user enters a character in the search field.

The API reply has separate fields for address, zip, city, county and so on, making it easy to split the result in to fields.